# How does this wiring work?

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat, thermostat-c-wire, wifi

I have a Trane XV90 and XL 14i. The wiring looks a little strange as in the picture bellow.

```
                  _____________
                  |           | 

BK W2  W1   R  G  Y  B/C  YLO O 
   |___||   |__|  ||   | 
        |   |     ||   |_____>|----------|
        |   |     ||_________>|other wire|
        |   |     |           ------------
        V   V     V
    ---------------
    |thermostat   |
    ---------------
```

The R and G are jumpered together and the G wire is connected on the board  but is actually not connecting to the thermostat on the other end. So people told me that means the furnace fan is always on! (In my diagram above, I switched the location of Y and B/C to make diagram easier to draw. You can refer to the photo added below to see the details)

My questions are the following

- is the jumper between O and Y doing anything? I don't think I have heat pump
- I need to install Honeywell wifi thermostat and I am thinking of doing either one of the following:

1. remove jumper between R and G, and use G to connect B/C and then to thermostat C and put jumper between G and Y
2. leave jumper between R and G, and use G to connect B/C and then to thermostat C and put jumper between G and Y
3. remove jumper between R and G, connect G on control board to thermostat G, and finally have the spare wire to connect B/C and then thermostat C
4. leave jumper between R and G, does not connect G to thermostat,  and just use a spare wire to connect B/C on board to thermostat C

Can anyone comment on those plans? Thanks a lot!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: First find out what you have! 
Don’t start disconnecting things you don’t understand. Do you need a Honeywell? Is asking if you need a ford or some other brand of thermostat. Changing your fan and cooling wiring can really mess things up. Is your furnace on or in fan on mode the thermostat may have it commanded on depending on the controls for your specific system.

Comment: Thanks Ed. I just got a Honeywell 8500 in box and want to use it. So I guess the way of tying might be just use a spare wire to connect to B/C on board and C on thermostat, without connecting G to thermostat. Just like the option 4 I just added? Thanks.

Comment: This actually helps I would integrate this info into your other question and delete this one I think you will get more assistance that way. The new stat probably will have a switch to jumper r to c built in so I would remove that and check functionality.

Comment: How many wires do you have in your existing thermostat cable? Can you post a wiring diagram for your furnace/air-handler, or a link to the manual for that matter?

Comment: There are only R W Y connected in my current thermostat. I don't have manual for my furnace and will look up online. The brand and model are Trane XV90 for furnace and XL 14i for AC.

Comment: I found this http://homeappliance.manualsonline.com/manuals/mfg/trane/upflowhorizontal_twostage_condensing_gasfired_furnace_xv_90_tuy060080100120r9v_variable_speed_blower_variable_speed_inducer.html?p=11, not sure if it is the right manual.

Comment: @DpD_ -- do you have spare wires in said thermostat cable, or just the three that are connected? Perhaps some photos of the wiring at both ends would help?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel How to add photo? The green wire's one end is connected to the furnace control board, and the other end of the green wire is dangling near the thermostat, but not connected so I can use it. There are some spare wires hiding. If I want to use those spares, I will have to cut all shorter and then use stripper to make those spared ones available to connect between control board and thermostat.

Comment: @DpD_ -- hit [edit] in the "share edit ..." links at the bottom left of your post, then use the "mountain and sun" button in the editor toolbar to add photos

Comment: What happens if you remove the jumper from the O wire?

Comment: I did not try to change anything yet. Do you have any guess on what will happen if I remove the jumper from O? I thought O is for heat pump usually, is that right? I don't think I have a heat pump. Anyway, I was thinking of remove jumper between R and G and connect the C wire to thermostat. My stripper just does not work well and I'm waiting for a new one to come. After I get it, I may start to try things, and hopefully I will not break any parts.

Comment: @DpD_ -- removing the jumper from O shouldn't break things, but testing it is the only way we can know for sure

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I will try to experiment things to see what will happen. BTW, if I remove jumper from O, which part of the furnace will likely be affected? It may not have any effect on AC I guess. So I may have to test heating a little?

Comment: @DpD_ -- I suspect the primary effect will be on fan operation, so you'll want to test heating, cooling, and fan-only modes

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I searched online and it seems the Y O jumper is used to 'activate' Trane's comfort-r feature. I don't know what exactly this feature is about but it seems to help to control the humidity level inside the house by controlling the fan speed. So you are right on this!

Comment: I just realized that the G wire never connected to the thermostat since  the t-stat and the furnace were installed (at least it is true for the t-stat) So I decided to just use the G wire to connect to the C on control board and the new t-stat, and leave everything else alone. It is now working to control both heat and cool, so I guess it is a partial success at least. But I still don't know why and does not really like to have jumper between R and G as the fan on furnace is always running. I may have to deal with it or change it some time soon. For now, I just leave it as it maybe.

Comment: @DpD_ -- many modern furnace control boards have a feature that can reduce the fan speed during cooling cycles when signaled; as you allude to, it's used for humidity control as it helps the air conditioner dehumidify more efficiently.  (It basically shifts the latent/sensible balance of the air conditioner, by giving each parcel of air more time to hang around the cold coil and give up moisture as condensation.)